# mnesia: delete rows with key other than primary key used to insert

Tags: erlang

- I created a table with record `#record{x, y}`
- When inserted, I used `x` as primary key
- During read operations I use x as primary key

But I need to delete using `y`

Which api I can use to delete with `y`

Please provide me an example.

My table

```
         mnesia:create_table(?TEST_TABLE,
               [{disc_only_copies, [node()]}, {type, bag},
               {attributes, record_info(fields, test_table)}]);
```

Answer (score 3):

Use mnesia:delete_object/1 or /3 [delete object](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/mnesia.html#delete_object-1)
You have to find the record you want to remove first.

```
mnesia:transaction(fun() -> mnesia:delete_object(table, Obj_to_del, write) end).
```